# Compilation failure on unneeded dependency of dependency

Tags: java, eclipse

I am attempting to compile my maven project, and I am depending on another project (which is a jar file). For some reason, when I attempt to compile I get the following error which seems to be that my project can not access the required dependencies of the project I'm depending on, even though I don't use any of those dependencies.

Here is the error http://hastebin.com/pebolozuxi.sql

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/cneth/Desktop/Developing/PrimeMC/PrimeMobWhacker/src/main/java/org/primemc/MobWhackerManager.java:[315,34] cannot access tech.rayline.core.plugin.RedemptivePlugin
  class file for tech.rayline.core.plugin.RedemptivePlugin not found
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.892 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-07T14:56:20+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/298M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project MobWhacker: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Users/cneth/Desktop/Developing/PrimeMC/PrimeMobWhacker/src/main/java/org/primemc/MobWhackerManager.java:[315,34] cannot access tech.rayline.core.plugin.RedemptivePlugin
[ERROR] class file for tech.rayline.core.plugin.RedemptivePlugin not found
```

I know that I can easily depend on that required dependency to solve the issue, however I don't see why that would be necessary so I wish to solve this issue without taking that route, if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of making people follow a link you could post that short snippet directly. You also might post some code since it's hard to tell with just that message and your very short description.

Comment: Do you have access to source? Find this class tech.rayline.core.plugin.RedemptivePlugin by typing ctrl+shift+t and type RedemptivePlugin in the breadcrump eclipse would show related jar and version

Comment: @Thomas Alright, sorry. I will next time. I usually do that but this error looked a bit annoying to read when I attempted to post it here.

Comment: So what happens at line 315 of MobWhackerManager.java?

Comment: @Thomas I call a method from one of my dependencies which depends on the project that contains `RedemptivePlugin.java`. (Posting the source wouldn't help anymore, its literally just a method with an irrelevant name). My project doesn't explicitly use `RedemptivePlugin.java`, however the project which I'm calling the method from does. Does that mean my project needs access to the `RedemptivePlugin.java` project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing to do with Maven. The *java compiler* wants that class. `MobWhackerManager.java:[315,34]`, in fact, wants that class. The line number is right there. Your code, at line 315, references that class somehow.

Comment: So, referencing a class that references `RedemptivePlugin.java` requires the `RedemptivePlugin.java`'s project to be a dependency of my project?

Comment: Without seeing the code at like 315 of that class, I can't sort you out further. But, in general, if you declare a field, invoke a method, whatever, yes, the compiler needs to see the .class file to tell how to compile it. perhaps you call something that returns an object of that type.

Comment: `PrimeSpawnerTiers.getInstance().getSpawnerTracker().getSpawnerMobs().dropLoot(event.getKilledEntity(), (stacked - newStacked)
    * getLootMultiplier(data));`

Comment: That is the line, its pretty irrelevant however. What is relevant is that the dependency `PrimeSpawnerTiers` itself depends on `RedemptivePlugin.java`, but my project does not directly use `RedemptivePlugin.java`.

Comment: I've simply added the `RedemptivePlugin.java`'s jar to my dependencies and its solved the problem. I just asked the original question in hopes there was a better way, but I didn't understand that I needed all referenced dependencies accessible by java. Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try excluding not needed transitive dependecy
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that the compiler misses the class `tech.rayline.core.plugin.RedemptivePlugin`.

So you probably need to add the jar with this class to your Maven dependencies.

Comment: I understand that, but my source code does not import anything from that project. I just call a method from one of my dependencies which depends on the project containing that class. I'm going to end up adding that dependency as one of my own to solve this error, but I was hoping there was a better way to go about solving this.

Comment: This is exactly the point: You need to have all classes that are transitively used by your project, i.e. also the classes that are used by a class that is used by a class that is used by you. Otherwise you can't compile. But that is exactly what Maven or Gradle is for: Gathering all transitive dependencies automatically.

Answer (score 0):

From your last comment I understand that you need the jar containing RedemptivePlugin so you must keep it.   In the worst case, download it manually with the right version and put it in your .m2 with the right path

*previous answear*
Juste to be able to help:
Have you checked the presence of your needed jar in your **.m2** ?
Have you checked the full dependencies of your project to state for sure that you don't need the jar containing the class tech.rayline.core.plugin.RedemptivePlugin.

If you are sure of that, try:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>The Project Jar That Links You To RedemptivePlugin Jar</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
      <version>TheVersion</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>The Jar containing RedemptivePlugin</groupId>
          <artifactId>theJar</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: From your last comment I understand that you need the jar containing RedemptivePlugin so you must keep it.   In the worst case, download it manually with the right version and put it in your .m2 with the right path

Comment: The jar I depend on actually depends on another jar which shades in the RedemptivePlugin's jar (bit of a lengthy depend chain, but should be understandable).

I was just hoping that there was a way for me to not directly depend on the RedemptivePlugin's jar, since I don't directly use it in my project. However I guess its required on my buildpath even if I don't directly use it.